# Instance variable not being set in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem with a Rails 4 app that used to work perfectly fine.  Now, an instance variable remains nil after being set.  In the controller, I have the following code:

```
def create
  @reportdate = Reportdate.new(reportdate_params)
  weekly_summary = getSOData(@reportdate.start_date, @reportdate.end_date)
  @reportdate.questions = weekly_summary[:question_ids]
  @reportdate.num_answers = weekly_summary[:answers]
  @reportdate.views = weekly_summary[:views]
  respond_to do |format|
  if @reportdate.save
  ...
```

When I run this, `@reportdate.num_answers` and `@reportdate.views` gets set, but `@reportdate.questions` remains `nil`.

When I run it in the debugger, I verified that `weekly_summary[:question_ids]` equals

`[21636454, 21539706, 21611661, 21632781, 21583630, 21614059, 21634704, 21615609, 21595829, 21564079, 21587196, 21537280]`.

This used to work before and I have no idea why it's not working now.

Comment: what type of a setter/database column is `questions`? I think the problem is within the `Reportdate` model setter.

Comment: when you put the debugger behind @reportdate.questions it's already nil? and weekly_summary[:question_ids] isn't?

Comment: any chance that `.save` is clearing that field because of validation errors or something?

Comment: Try with `save!`.It might be some validation error as @phoet said.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @reportdate = Reportdate.new(reportdate_params)
  weekly_summary = getSOData(@reportdate.start_date, @reportdate.end_date)

  @reportdate.questions   = weekly_summary[:question_ids]
  @reportdate.num_answers = weekly_summary[:answers]
  @reportdate.views       = weekly_summary[:views]

  respond_to do |format|
      if @reportdate.save
         ...
```

I think the answer is outside the scope of your controller. I changed the above to reflect the data used in the action, and as you can see, the main ways you receive data are from the `weekly_summary` method

I would check these:

1. Is `weekly_summary` populating the variable correctly?
2. Is `.questions` an attribute of the `Reportdate` object? If not, do you have an `attr_accessor`?
3. Your `Reportdate` object needs to be [`CamelCase`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) - should be `ReportDate` (this could cause an issue)
4. As mentioned in  the comments, your model may prevent saving due to validation issues.

---

All this points to some other part of the app having issues

Could you post your `Reportdate` model and `weekly_summary` code please?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for responding.  The problem was that I was setting the instance variable incorrectly.  I didn't think I made a change in that part of the code, but it was impossible to work the way it was written, so I must have.  It is all fixed and working now.